# Getting content from HttpResponseMessage for testing using c# dynamic keyword

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

In one of the actions, I do something like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Foo foo)
{
    .....
    .....

    var response = 
          Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, new { Token = "SOME_STRING_TOKEN"});
    return response;
}
```

and more methods like that return an anonymous type instance and it works well.

Now, I'm writing tests for it. I have

```
HttpResponseMessage response = _myController.Post(dummyFoo);
```

[`HttpResponseMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159046.aspx) has a property called [`Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.content.aspx) and has a `ReadAsAsync<T>()`.

I know that if there was a concrete specific type, I can do

```
Bar bar = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Bar>();
```

but how do I access the anonymous type that's being returned? Is it possible?

I was hoping to do the following:

```
dynamic responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
string returnedToken = responseContent.Token;
```

but I got the error that instance of type object does not have the property Token. This happens even though the debugger shows responseContent with one property Token. I understand why that's happening, but I want to know if there is a way to access the Property.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the type of `responseToken` (do `((object)responseContent.GetType())`). Thanks

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Object]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`.ReadAsAsync<T>` is an asynchronous method, meaning that it doesn't return the whole deserialized object but a `Task<T>` to handle the continuation of the whole asynchronous task.

You've two options:

#### 1. Async pattern.

Use the `async` keyword in your enclousing method (for example: `public async void A()`) and do the asynchronous call this way:

```
dynamic responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
string returnedToken = responseContent.Token;
```

#### 2. Regular task API

Or just use the Task API:

```
response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>().ContinueWith(task => {
   // The Task.Result property holds the whole deserialized object
   string returnedToken = ((dynamic)task.Result).Token;
});
```

It's up to you!

### Update

Before you posted the whole screenshot, no one could know that you're calling `task.Wait` in order to wait for the async result. But I'm going to maintain my answer because it may help further visitors :)

As I suggested in a comment to my own answer, you should try deserializing to `ExpandoObject`. ASP.NET WebAPI uses JSON.NET as its underlying JSON serializer. That is, it can handle anonymous JavaScript object deserialization to expando objects.

Comment: I have attached an image that shows the exception and the anonymous type with the property I am interested in. I don't know if I can make a unit test method async so I'll try option 2 and let you know.

Comment: @ProfessorChaos If you're calling an async method, you shouldn't mock it returning the value synchronously. You need to mimic the actual behavior. Please try something: deserialize `ExpandoObject` instead of `object`.

Comment: @ProfessorChaos Hmmm, now I understand what's happening. Please double-check my answer: you're using non of the options I'm trying to show you. Check the incoming update in my answer.

Comment: using ExpandoObject worked. that was what I was misssing. If you can edit your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @ProfessorChaos Done and hopefully you could solve your problem ;)

Comment: I'm not familiar with c# async concepts at all. I removed the Wait() and since I'm calling it in a synchronous fashion (without await), it didn't make any difference. Thanks for your help with `ExpandoObject` though!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the similar following code to test the HttpResponseMessage using Unit Testing.

This worked for me.

Hope this will help you

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Post_Test()
        {
           //Arrange
           var contoller = new PostController();  //the contoller which you want to test
           controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
           controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

           // Act
           var response = controller.Post(new Number { PhNumber = 9866190822 });
           // Number is the Model name and PhNumber is the Model Property for which you want to write the unit test

           //Assert
           var request = response.StatusCode;
           Assert.AreEqual("Accepted", request.ToString());

        }
    }
```

Similarly according to the need change the HttpResponseMessage in the Assert.